# spring boot: what dependencies are needed make a simple spring boot app with domain objects, services and web controllers (similar to grails?)

Tags: spring-boot

I come from grails where all config and setup is done for you, and you just write domain code (such as domain objects, services and controllers). No puglins, no mvn configuration, no pain.

Now Im trying to setup a spring boot project, where i can just add domain objects, and the framework handles creating them int a database, creating indexes and relationships etc, and I can just query the data with java instead of hand writing sql.

Following this tutorial to create a spring boot project: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot

It says "install the required dependencies", and there is a very long list, including things like:

1. spring web
2. spring boot dev tools
3. spring configuration processor
4. spring session
5. spring web services
6. spring security
7. JDBI api
8. spring data JPA

etc.
etc.

I had assumed spring boot had everything you need already included, including ORM, JDBC, web services etc

Am I wrong?  is spring boot nothing more than a bare spring app, where you have to manually install every required dependency (requiring significant expertise and knowledge)?

How do I know which of the many dependencies I need to make a spring boot app, so I can just start coding a basic backend for a web application?

Answer (score 2):

`Spring Boot` is a wrapper over `Spring MVC` framework that enables auto-configuration and improves productivity of the developer. The developer can spend more time on the business logic rather than configuring it.

`Spring Boot` doesn't come with all the dependencies preinstalled. That would just be crazy. Imagine having a `grails` project that has all the possible dependencies in the world. That's just not possible right? You need to decide which ones are required and install them. Similar concept applies to `Spring Boot`

`Spring boot` has a lot of starter dependencies that improve your productivity.

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `spring-boot-starter` | Core starter, including auto-configuration support, logging, and YAML |
| `spring-boot-starter-activemq` | Starter for JMS messaging using Apache ActiveMQ |
| `spring-boot-starter-amqp` | Starter for using Spring AMQP and Rabbit MQ |
| `spring-boot-starter-aop` | Starter for aspect-oriented programming with Spring AOP and AspectJ |
| `spring-boot-starter-artemis` | Starter for JMS messaging using Apache Artemis |
| `spring-boot-starter-batch` | Starter for using Spring Batch |
| `spring-boot-starter-cache` | Starter for using Spring Framework’s caching support |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` | Starter for using Cassandra distributed database and Spring Data Cassandra |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive` | Starter for using Cassandra distributed database and Spring Data Cassandra Reactive |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase` | Starter for using Couchbase document-oriented database and Spring Data Couchbase |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase-reactive` | Starter for using Couchbase document-oriented database and Spring Data Couchbase Reactive |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` | Starter for using Elasticsearch search and analytics engine and Spring Data Elasticsearch |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` | Starter for using Spring Data JDBC |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` | Starter for using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-ldap` | Starter for using Spring Data LDAP |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` | Starter for using MongoDB document-oriented database and Spring Data MongoDB |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive` | Starter for using MongoDB document-oriented database and Spring Data MongoDB Reactive |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` | Starter for using Neo4j graph database and Spring Data Neo4j |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc` | Starter for using Spring Data R2DBC |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` | Starter for using Redis key-value data store with Spring Data Redis and the Lettuce client |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive` | Starter for using Redis key-value data store with Spring Data Redis reactive and the Lettuce client |
| `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` | Starter for exposing Spring Data repositories over REST using Spring Data REST |
| `spring-boot-starter-freemarker` | Starter for building MVC web applications using FreeMarker views |
| `spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates` | Starter for building MVC web applications using Groovy Templates views |
| `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` | Starter for building hypermedia-based RESTful web application with Spring MVC and Spring HATEOAS |
| `spring-boot-starter-integration` | Starter for using Spring Integration |
| `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` | Starter for using JDBC with the HikariCP connection pool |
| `spring-boot-starter-jersey` | Starter for building RESTful web applications using JAX-RS and Jersey. An alternative to spring-boot-starter-web |
| `spring-boot-starter-jooq` | Starter for using jOOQ to access SQL databases. An alternative to spring-boot-starter-data-jpa or `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` |
| `spring-boot-starter-json` | Starter for reading and writing json |
| `spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos` | Starter for JTA transactions using Atomikos |
| `spring-boot-starter-mail` | Starter for using Java Mail and Spring Framework’s email sending support |
| `spring-boot-starter-mustache` | Starter for building web applications using Mustache views |
| `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` | Starter for using Spring Security’s OAuth2/OpenID Connect client features |
| `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` | Starter for using Spring Security’s OAuth2 resource server features |
| `spring-boot-starter-quartz` | Starter for using the Quartz scheduler |
| `spring-boot-starter-rsocket` | Starter for building RSocket clients and servers |
| `spring-boot-starter-security` | Starter for using Spring Security |
| `spring-boot-starter-test` | Starter for testing Spring Boot applications with libraries including JUnit Jupiter, Hamcrest and Mockito |
| `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` | Starter for building MVC web applications using Thymeleaf views |
| `spring-boot-starter-validation` | Starter for using Java Bean Validation with Hibernate Validator |
| `spring-boot-starter-web` | Starter for building web, including RESTful, applications using Spring MVC. Uses Tomcat as the default embedded container. |
| `spring-boot-starter-web-services` | Starter for using Spring Web Services |
| `spring-boot-starter-webflux` | Starter for building WebFlux applications using Spring Framework’s Reactive Web support |
| `spring-boot-starter-websocket` | Starter for building WebSocket applications using Spring Framework’s WebSocket support |

Now,depending on the needs of your project you should start adding the starter dependencies to your `pom.xml` file and then rebuild the project.

For instance, if you wanted to build just a simple rest api, you would use the `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-data-jpa` dependencies.

To ease this process, you can create your project via [Spring Initialzr](https://start.spring.io/), as it gives you a brief idea about what the dependency does, when you're adding it to your project.

I would also recommend you to watch a tutorial that shows how to get started with Spring boot.

###### References:

[Spring Boot - Full Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SGDpanrc8U)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Are all these *-starter-* dependencies already included, or do they have to be manually added?  what is the difference between "spring-boot-starter-web" and "spring-boot-web".  I dont really see what boot gives you over spring if you still have to install a bunch of stuff to get a basic web app started (its all out of the box with grails - you dont have to setup hibernate, persistence for default DB, anything related to web or rest).

Comment: Where have you seen `spring-boot-web`? As far as I know, there's no such thing as `spring-boot-web`, it's just `spring-boot-starter-web` which might have been referred to as `spring-boot-web` somewhere. Rest of all the questions are already answered in my post, please read it carefully. Also, go through the reference I've provided above.

Answer (score 1):

Just need starter-web for the web part (rest/soap/whatever), starter-data-jpa for the db/orm part, and the proper JDBC driver. More info here: https://spring.io/projects
That's a simple pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>VERSION</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -3):

Spring Initialzr will create the project for you.  Just select what you need.
https://start.spring.io/